# Nagios Core Disabled CFG files

Tags: networking, configuration, monitoring, nagios3

I have multiple host cfg files that we renamed to disabled with the, mv , command. We did this to take them off our dashboard view.

When we try to rename them back to regular files, and attempt to restart Nagios it generates this error message

See "systemct1 status nagios.service" and "journalct1 -xe" for details.

From what I can tell this is being caused by renaming our cfg files. Here's my problem/question.

1. How do we re-enable cfg files without causing this error?

Edit: It is on Ubunutu version 20.04.5

Edit 2: I re-created the error, checked the logs, and found it saying HostNAME is not a valid parent for HOSTNAME. Not sure if I am including extra characters or something else at this point but working on it.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written doesn't make any reference to the Ubuntu OS. Can you please include the version of Ubuntu that you're using. Thanks

Comment: @richbl Added thank you for asking, if more information is needed I'm happy update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to multiple host groups to enable cfg files in each one.

Once all the parent files and all related files were renamed with MV command it allowed a restart and brought the hosts back to the Nagios dashboard.